# How does c++ nested template class work?

Tags: c++, class, templates, nested

I have the following example TestC is a template class. Class test uses a template class as template and there is a special member_ which is nested instantiation A >. However, the compiler complaint about this point. Is this illegal? Or how to correct it?

Thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class A>
class TestC {
    public:
    TestC(double a = 100.0) : a_(a) {};
    A member_;
    double a_;
};

template <template <class> class A>
class Test {
    public:
    Test(A<Test<A> > member = A<Test<A> >() );
    A<Test<A> > member_;
};

int main() {
    TestC< Test<TestC> > a(10.0);
    return 0;
}
```

> Compilation error time: 0 memory: 3292 signal:0prog.cpp: In
>   instantiation of ‘class Test’: prog.cpp:8:7:   required from
>   ‘class TestC >’ prog.cpp:21:23:   required from here
>   prog.cpp:16:17: error: ‘Test::member_’ has incomplete type
>        A > member_;
>                    ^ prog.cpp:5:7: error: declaration of ‘class TestC >’  class TestC {

```
   ^
```

Comment: I'm guessing you meant `TestC< Test<TestC> > a;`, as it stands you are declaring a function called `a`.

Comment: if I changed to e.g. TestC< Test<TestC> > a(10.0); I think I am constructing an object of TestC< Test<TestC> >, still error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class

```
template <template <class> class A>
class Test {
    public:
    Test(A<Test<A> > member = A<Test<A> >() );
    A<Test<A> > member_;
    //^^^^^^^ this requires Test to be defined completely.
};
```

is analogous to

```
class Test
{
   Test member_;
};
```

Definition of `class Test` isn't over before you are defining a member variable that depends on the complete class definition.

In a regular class, you can use a pointer to the class as a member.

```
class Test
{
   Test* member_;
};
```

You can do a similar thing with the class template. Here's program that builds successfully.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class A>
class TestC {
    public:
    TestC(double a = 100.0) : a_(a) {}
    A member_;
    double a_;
};

template <template <class> class A>
class Test {
    public:
    Test() {}
    A<Test<A>* > member_;
};

int main() {
    TestC< Test<TestC> > a;

    // type of a is TestC< Test<TestC> >
    // It has a member member_.
    // type of a.member_ is Test<TestC>
    // a.member_ has a member member_
    // type of a.member_.member_ is TestC<Test<TestC>*>
    // a.member_.member_ has a member whose type is Test<TestC>*
    // You can assign nullptr to it.
    a.member_.member_.member_ = nullptr;

    // Or you can assign to it a pointer to an object allocated from the heap.
    a.member_.member_.member_ = new Test<TestC>;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, change to pointer is not what I could do.